# OpenCL the same algorithms for GPU and CPU but OpenCl works differently for those two devices

Tags: multithreading, opencl, gpu, cpu

I have two programs written by me from scratch, one is integral and second matrix-matrix multiplication. When I was executing both programs with GPU cards, and I set global size to 1024 I expected kernel code to execute 1024 times, and it was correct, it was executing the same amount of times as I set on global size, and changing local size did not matter to code results and to output.
The same code I tried to execute with CPU, and I was shocked when I saw that kernel function does not executes the same amount of times as in global size was set. Here is the example from integral:
global size = 2048, local size = 1,
I am expecting 2048 executions of kernel function, and yes, it is 2048,
but when we have global size = 2048 and local size = 16 then it executes 256 times...
Is it normal? Why working with CPU is different in openCl than with GPU? I thought that it does not matter for user side which device we use, the same code should work the same on different devices. Am I wrong guys?

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: We need a [Minimal, Compilable, Veriable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. So please post some code and how you're enqueuing it (and with which OpenCL driver etc.) In general, the driver is supposed to ensure the entire grid is executed, i.e. local work size times global work size threads executing overall.

Comment: There must be wrong interception of global thread id and group id and local thread id. How are you checking number of executions?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I just simply add +=1 to global variable in kernel code to see how many times kernel was executed

Comment: @Gzyniu is it atomic or a simple one? I mean, did you use atomic_add() or really += ?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik simple one, but I checked atomic_add and same results here

Comment: @Gzyniu which global variable?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik passed as an argument to kernel func. (as __global float* c)

Comment: @Gzyniu atomic increment doesn't work on float(or at least you should interpret it as an integer at host side) and check if zero integer is not denied in floating point format.

Comment: Are you using vectors and is the GPU an NVIDIA card?

Answer (score 0):

Use atomic operations for serial work (or at least non-easily-reducible). To count how many threads participated, don't use `a[0]+=1;`

```
atomic_add(&a[0],1);
```

should work or even better

```
atomic_inc(a)
```

where a is an integer, unsigned signed doesn't matter.

Comment: ok, yes, atomic_inc does not work eighter. I mean it does its job, incrementing value but this value is different than global size at the end. I dont get it, I have a code that works perfectly on 1, 2 or even 8 gpu's but when I swiched to CPU (I did not forgot to change clgetDeviceIds argument to CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU) it acts weird... different values than on GPU's. Is there something different about working with CPU's instead of GPU's?

Comment: I fixed the problem with different results but still I have a problem with CPU and GPU working differently. I implemented integral in kernel that way: we have int id = get_global_id(0) and even if we set global size extremally big, every thread will get smaller piece of work to do, but on CPU I see that if I set local_size = 4096 (it is max) in kernel I have threads numbered from 0 to 4095 ... why? I am fetching global id not local... in GPU it was working when local size was set to 1 and to 1024 and no such problem seen. Why is that?

Comment: I am not asking why it ends with 4095 but why it not ends with globalsize-1. On GPU when I set globalsize as 1234567, my last thread was numbered 1234566, but now, even if implementation is the same it now ends with localsize-1

Answer (score 0):

I found out the source of the problem. It was because of float's poor precision, when I changed variables to double it works fine. I read somewhere that CPU and GPU in terms of floating point operations, work slightly different regarding precision.